# Capturing an “HD” video from Webcam using gstreamer pipeline failed

Tags: video, webcam, gstreamer, video-capture, pipeline

I have a simple pipeline which is supposed to capture a video stream (+audio) from a webcam in JPEG and put it into a .mts container, but at the end when I try to play the file (using ffplay) or convert it to other format (e.g mp4) I get some errors like "EOI is missing" or "found two EOI" or "bad decoder"...

Can you please tell me which part of this pipeline is wrong? How shall I change it to get a smooth video stream inside a .mts container  at the end?

here is the pipeline:

```
 gst-launch-1.0   v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! videorate  ! 'image/jpeg,framerate=30/1,width=1920,height=1080' !\
    queue ! mux. \
pulsesrc device="alsa_input.usb-046d_Logitech_Webcam_C930e_AAF8A63E-02-C930e.analog-stereo" !\
    'audio/x-raw,rate=44100,channels=1,depth=24' ! \
    audioconvert !  avenc_aac compliance=experimental ! queue ! mux. \
matroskamux name="mux" !\
    filesink location=/home/Webcam.mts
```

Comment: you are using matroskamux and expecting it to be .mts ? how do you convert this to other format? which format? are you able to play this file in gstreamer?

Comment: actually I was using matroskamux for .mkv but now I want the whole video+audio stream into .mts container
yes, I can play it via ffplay (still has some errors at the openning the file but plays it)
I'm not a professional in gstreamer, sorry if this question looks stupid...
Right now I just want the correct result to be into .mts (in the future I'll convert them to .mp4 via another extension in other program) without any frame drops or errors...

Comment: what exactly do you expect to be in .mts? - just images and aac - is this ok? I didnt find any encoders/ muxers for such format - I searched AVC AVCHD mts .. (is this container or codec?). Can you not output to just raw mpeg ts stream?

Comment: Well, I need to capture a HD video stream (+audio) from my webcam but apparently this type of Webcam captures in HD only using Jpeg (or better to say in MJPEG) format and I need the playable result to be inside a .mts container.
It's not important if the pipeline needs to be changed, the only thing that matters here is the final result, Thanks a lot for your help in advance